# How to correctly handle AVPlayer HTTP error?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When requesting to play a mp3 file from a web server, if that server returns a 403 forbidden it is not clear how to handle the error when examining the AVPlayer current item error.

Error message from AVPlayer doesn't indicate that it is a 403...

> 2019-01-05 13:08:33.908316-0500 Runner[84043:3269818] Optional(Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not
>   supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000781290 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-12847 "(null)"}})

The error says the media isn't supported, but the media was never even reached. Is there anyway to see the HTTP error code from AVPlayer requests?

When testing the same file on Android, I am able to correctly see a 403 error code from Android native `MediaPlayer` (the error from Android is better and more useful than iOS's AVPlayer).

This lack of proper error messaging makes it very difficult to gracefully display an accurate error to the user.

Arbitrary Code sample:

```
    let url = URL(string: "some 403 server url")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.play()
```

Checking the error will print the above quoted message.

```
NSLog("\(String(describing: player.currentItem?.error))")
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Added some arbitrary code, the code is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, Rather than initializing the `AVPlayerItem` with a url

You can try this approach

1. Use `AVURLAsset` and set the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`
2. Use the delegate method
     `func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader:AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel authenticationChallenge:  URLAuthenticationChallenge)`
3. Proceed to create the player and play audio, The delegate method will let you know when there is a 403 error.

Here's the sample code

```
class ResourceLoadingDelegate:NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
      func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader,
                    didCancel authenticationChallenge:  URLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    /// handle the authentication challenge
    print(authenticationChallenge.error.debugDescription)
   }
}

   let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "some 403 url")!)

   asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(ResourceLoadingDelegate(), queue:  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
```

Comment: This is a fair answer, but `playable` or `not playable` does not exactly indicate why it is not playable. The reason is `403` I would like to be able to see that.

Comment: In this case you can use `URLSession.shared.downloadTask` can check the `response.status_code` is not `200`

Comment: is this after checking isPlayable?

Comment: I have updated the solution to address your concerns

Comment: Interesting, this is downloading the full file isn't it? is this how AVPlayerItem does it as well or does it buffer? 

Downloading the full file before playing seems slow, there must be a better way

Comment: I think I will circumvent all of this with a simple HEAD request to see if resource exists, effectively the HEAD will just give a response code and no content. This seems like overkill otherwise.

Comment: Found this information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1643630-preferredforwardbufferduration

The player seems to buffer indeed.

Comment: Check out the new solution it uses the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`

Answer (score 8):

Use KVO to Observe the playItem's status like this:

```
self.playItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Then in the method :

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        let playerItem = object as! AVPlayerItem
        if keyPath == "status", playerItem.status == .failed{
            if let error = playerItem.error as NSError? {
                let errorCode = error.code
            }
        }
}
```

You can find the codes defines here:
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1448136-nserror_codes)