# AVPlayer not playing in Xcode12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, avplayer

I'm trying to play an  video from photo library with AVPlayer but for some reason I can't get it to work. I've been trying to read every question about this but none of the suggested answers seems to work.

Is my code wrong or do I need to do something else to make it work? Enable it in capabilities or something similar?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let videoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()

// MARK:- UI Elements
    let SelectVideoBtn : UIButton = {
        let a = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        a.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        a.setTitle("Select Video", for: .normal)
        a.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        a.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        a.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SelectAVideo(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return a
    }()
    
    let MasterPreviewView : UIView = {
        let a = UIView()
        a.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        a.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1)
        a.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        return a
    }()
    
    let HorizontalToolStack : UIStackView = {
        let a = UIStackView()
        a.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        a.axis = .horizontal
        a.distribution  = .equalSpacing
        a.alignment = .fill
        a.spacing = 20
        
        return a
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // delegates and data stuff
        videoPickerController.delegate = self
        
        // Selection Button
        self.view.addSubview(SelectVideoBtn)
        SelectVideoBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        SelectVideoBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        SelectVideoBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        SelectVideoBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        // Master Preview View
        self.view.addSubview(MasterPreviewView)
        MasterPreviewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SelectVideoBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        MasterPreviewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        MasterPreviewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        MasterPreviewView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
        
        MasterPreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=A0FBB444-15D7-4ED2-9EB2-922E4FB11F7A&ext=MP4")
        PlayVideo(inView: MasterPreviewView, pathToVideo: videoURL!)
    }

    internal func VideoPicker(){
        videoPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        videoPickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        videoPickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(videoPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
// MARK:- Delegate Methods
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as? NSURL
        print(videoURL!)
        videoPickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // Now Play the Selected Video
        PlayVideo(inView: MasterPreviewView, pathToVideo: videoURL!)
    }
    
    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("Selection Cancelled")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
// MARK:- Button Selectors
    
    @objc func SelectAVideo(sender : UIButton){
        VideoPicker()
    }
    //MARK:- Custom Functions
    /**
         A function to play a video in the View of our choice.
     
     - Parameter inView : Specify the view in which youo want the video player to play your video
     - Parameter pathToVide : The path of the video you want to play
     */
    private func PlayVideo(inView parentView : UIView, pathToVideo urlPath : NSURL) {
        // Downcasting the NSURL to URL
        let player = AVPlayer(url: urlPath as URL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        let playerLayerAV = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        //now we set the size of frame to be like the view ("backview")
        
        playerLayerAV.frame = parentView.bounds
        parentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayerAV)
        player.play()
        
        player.rate = 0.5
    }

}
```

Comment: I've also tried force playing it from ViewDidLoad but that also doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: What about trying to read errors? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054853/how-to-correctly-handle-avplayer-http-error Also, why combine `NSURL` and `URL`? Just use `URL`, you won't have to cast (as) afterwards both ways.

Comment: Not related but: name your var and your methods starting with a lowercase, that's convention. Avoid NSSuff when possible if Stuff (without the NS) is available (like NSURL/URL). Also XCode12? Why using a Beta version? Is it working in a "stable/official" version? Could it be related to Beta and not about your code?

Comment: cant see your imports, have you imported the correct library